# Определение подключения к интернет на андроид ConnectivityManager

Tags: android, java

Всем добрый вечер. Есть задача программного определения наличия связи с интернет на андроид девайсе. Делаю следующим образом, но в любом случае показывает отсутствие соединения.

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
    timer = new Timer("DigitalClock");
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    saveText();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int god = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    String time = String.format("%02d/%02d/%02d", day, month, god);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (cm == null) {
        txt.setText("Отсутствует соединение");
    }
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo == null) {
        txt.setText("Отсутствует соединение");
    }
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) 
    {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")) {
            if (ni.isConnected()) {
                txt.setText(time);
            }
        }
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")) {
            if (ni.isConnected()) {
                txt.setText(time);
            }
        }
    txt.setText("Отсутствует соеденение");
    }

      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: В манифесте точно всё указано для доступа к сети?

Comment: Да! Я с ней работаю из других активностей.
Вот что у меня в манифесте:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

Comment: У вас в цикле в любом случае пишется "отсутствует соединение".

Comment: Как это. Если подключение есть то должно высветиться текущее время.

Comment: Да, оно высвечивается, скорее всего в некоторых случаях, но на такое время, которое не заметно человеческому глазу. Последнее `txt.setText("Отсутствует соеденение");` вынесите из цикла ниже.

Comment: Ой ой ой точно! Вечер уже. Спасибо. Тупить начинаю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public final class NetworkUtils {
    public static boolean isNetworkConnectedOrConnecting(Context context) {
        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
}
```